# How to locate Axis2 logs

Tags: apache-axis

I have deployed Axis2 war (1.6.1) on my Tomcat server and installed one of my test web service.
When I run any of my service methods using a sample application, it fails with the undermentioned error message.
I would like to check Axis2 logs to see what went wrong, but not sure where are these located.
Any ideas?

Error message:-
`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method TestInsert
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.ws.axis2.STStub.testInsert(STStub.java:1443)
    at org.apache.ws.axis2.WSTSample2.main(WSTSample2.java:33)`

Answer (score 1):

The Axis2 WAR comes prepackaged with log4j and is configured to log to System.out. In Tomcat, these logs should end up in catalina.log (but this may depend on the Tomcat version or configuration). If you are unable to locate the logs, you may want to remove the log4j JAR from the Axis2 WAR so that logs are sent to JULI (I'm assuming here that if you are familiar with Tomcat, you know what JULI is and how to use it).